# Sequential watch calls in Redis

Tags: transactions, redis, optimistic-locking

Is this pattern legal?

```
$redis->watch('foo');
$var1 = $redis->get('foo');

$redis->watch('bar');
$var2 = $redis->get('bar');


$redis->multi();
$redis->mset(['foo' => 42, 'bar' => 9001]);
$redis->exec();
```

Or second watch call cancels first watching state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is legal. From [redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)

> WATCH can be called multiple times. Simply all the WATCH calls will have the effects to watch for changes starting from the call, up to the moment EXEC is called. You can also send any number of keys to a single WATCH call.

Comment: Maybe you have such expirience in production?

Comment: Yes i have. You want to ask something else?